# How elegantly to call methods with various order?

Tags: java, python, algorithm

I have four methods:

```
right();
up();
left();
down();
```

Then I call them in the following fashion:

```
result = right();
if checkResult(result)
  return(result);

result = up();
if checkResult(result)
  return(result);

result = left();
if checkResult(result)
  return(result);

result = down();
if checkResult(result)
  return(result);
```

So it's kind of priority. I know that one of them would work. But I need to check it according to priority: `[right, up, left, down]`.

Now, the trick is: my priority changes over time. To be precise it depends on previous move. So:

```
if previous move was up(), then priority is [right, up, left, down]
if previous move was left(), then priority is [up, left, down, right]
if previous move was down(), then priority is [left, down, right, up]
```

So you can clearly see the logic here. The question is: how do I do call the functions in given (variable) priority?

Obviously, I can just do switch and copy-paste calling block, but that's ugly. So is it an elegant way of doing it?

Furthermore, what are the ways for Java and Python?

Comment: Why two languages? Why not focus on the problem in *one*?

Comment: Just do it the ugly way and move on...I would argue it's not really going to be that ugly nor that much code and it will probably be the most readable solution

Comment: Do you mean every time you call up() the next call will be right() and then down() and then left()..? Could you please post the code you have?

Comment: Set the priority, then use a for loop to call the functions in order of priority.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I encountered the problem in Java, but also curious if that's easier to solve in python (so far everything is way easier in python).

Comment: @Barodapride I agree, in general, but the purpose of this problem - is learning of the language (or design in general) power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assign the methods with integer ID's, e.g:

```
right() - 0
up() - 1
left() - 2
down() - 3
```

I would store the previousMove as an integer which corresponds to the last method which was called. So whenever up() is called, previousMove becomes equal to 1, etc. (You can set this wherever you need to based on your desired logic)

Then I would loop as follows:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int previousMove = 3; //Change this to test

        int startMethod = previousMove - 1 < 0 ? 3 : previousMove - 1; //Represents the ID of the method before the previousMove, accounting for negative values and wrapping around
        int offset = startMethod - 1 < 0 ? 3 : startMethod - 1; //Represents the ID of the method before the startMethod, accounting for negative values and wrapping around

        for (int i = startMethod; true; i++) {
            if (i > 3) i = 0; //Wrap around
            switch (i) {
                case 0: right(); break;
                case 1: up(); break;
                case 2: left(); break;
                case 3: down(); break;
            }
            if (i == offset) break; //Break once all 4 methods have been called
        }
    }

    private static void right() {
        System.out.println("Calling right");
    }

    private static void up() {
        System.out.println("Calling up");
    }

    private static void left() {
        System.out.println("Calling left");
    }

    private static void down() {
        System.out.println("Calling down");
    }
}
```

Output with previousMove = 3 (down):

```
Calling left
Calling down
Calling right
Calling up
```

Explaination: We are looping from startMethod (one before previousMove) all the way through the 4 methods until we have called them all. So if your "previous move" is the left() method, for example, you would set previousMove to 2, and the loop would go through calling the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th methods, as required.

The integers might be hard to get your head around at first but I can assure you that you will benefit much more by trying to understand the above code rather than just copy + pasting it into your program :)

Comment: Thank you @Norbo11 ! That's pretty much what I ended up doing as well. It just really loses the readability though :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a `dict` in python with the last mo e as your keys and the list of moves, sorted by priority as values.

Then you could additionaly save the last move and iterate over the corresponding list and do what you need to do with them.

Answer (score 1):

It is just as you wrote in the problem. When a key is pressed, change a list to reflect the desired priority:

```
# global, before continuous update

order = [right, up, left, down]

# during continuous update

# 1. Test for Key Presses
# 2. Change Priorities

if left_is_pressed: 
    order = [up, left, down, right]

# 3. call functions in order

for key_function in order:
    key_function()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a dict to define the direction check methods + another to define the priorities could be what you want. You might want to modify the method that checks if that key is pressed (or checks the condition) also returns the direction, so that it could be returned back from the top-level method that checks all input conditions. That direction can then be stored as the 'previous' direction and be used to check the next condition.

```
UP = 1
DOWN = 2
RIGHT = 3
LEFT = 4
# Assuming that `result` is the result of that method
def should_go_up():
    return (result, UP)
def should_go_down():
    return (result, DOWN)
def should_go_right():
    return (result, RIGHT)
def should_go_left():
    return (result, LEFT)

input_checks = {
   UP: should_go_up,
   DOWN: should_go_down,
   RIGHT: should_go_right,
   LEFT: should_go_left
}

input_check_priorities = {
    UP:[RIGHT, UP, LEFT, DOWN],
    LEFT:[UP, LEFT, DOWN, RIGHT],
    ...
}

def move(prev_move):
    if prev_move is None:
        prev_move = UP # or whatever is the default
    input_check_priority = input_check_priorites[prev_move]
    for direction in input_check_priority:
        result = input_checks[direction]()
        if result[0]:
            return result
    return (False, None)
```